# Proving $x|x|$ is differentiable for all $x$

Tags: real-analysis

$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $ f(x)= x|x| $ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Prove that the function $f$ is differentiable, and find a formula for its derivative  $f':\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

solution:

I have attempted using  $\lim_{x\to a} = \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ = $\frac{x|x|-a|a|}{x-a}$

I don't know how to simplify this or go any further?

Comment: See why there is no problem on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. Then at $0$, consider the limit when $x$ tends to $0$ of $$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$

Comment: The limit is to $a$, not to $0$.

Comment: Analyze cases when $a$ is positive, negative, or zero.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition is not quite correct.  The derivative should be $$f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a},$$ that is to say, the derivative of $f$ evaluated at $a$ is the limit as $x$ approaches $a$, not $0$.

If you use the correct definition, then you have three cases:  first, if $a > 0$, then $|a| = a$, and for a sufficiently small neighborhood around $a$, we would also have $|x| = x$ as $x \to a$, thus the quotient becomes $$\frac{x^2 - a^2}{x-a} = x + a$$ and the limit is $2a$.

Second, if $a < 0$, then $|a| = -a$ and again, in a sufficiently small neighborhood around $a$, we may assume $|x| = -x$, and the rest of the computation is similar.

The third case is if $a = 0$.  Here, we need to evaluate $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x|x|}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} |x| = 0.$$  Therefore, the derivative exists for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: surely youd get -2a for the second one though and -2a $\neq$ 2a and also neither are equal to 0 so how does this show it?

Comment: @anonymous The definition of derivative only requires that **the limit exists**, not that it is constant as a function of $a$.  Think about this.  The derivative of $f(x) = x^3$ at $x = a$ is $f'(a) = 3a^2$, which is not constant as a function of $a$.  One may also write that the derivative of $f(x) = x|x|$ at $x = a$ is $f'(a) = 2|a|$.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly to show that you can do things with only two cases ($a=0$ and $a\not=0$) instead of three ($a=0$, $a\gt0$, and $a\lt0$), using the fact that $|u|^2=u^2$.

If $a=0$ we have

$${x|x|-a|a|\over x-a}=|x|\to0$$

For $a\not=0$, we have

$$\begin{align}
{x|x|-a|a|\over x-a}
&={x^2|x|^2-a^2|a|^2\over(x-a)(x|x|+a|a|)}\\
&={x^4-a^4\over(x-a)(x|x|+a|a|)}\\
&={x^3+ax^2+a^2x+a^3\over x|x|+a|a|}\\
&\to{4a^3\over2a|a|}=2a|a|
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

If $a>0$, you can work in a neighborhood of $a$ such that $x>0$, and

$$\frac{x|x|-a|a|}{x-a}=\frac{x^2-a^2}{x-a}.$$

If $a<0$, you can work in a neighborhood of $a$ such that $x<0$, and

$$\frac{x|x|-a|a|}{x-a}=-\frac{x^2-a^2}{x-a}.$$

If $a=0$,

$$\frac{x|x|-0}{x-0}$$ simplifies to $|x|$ for $x\ne0$.

---

Alternatively, the derivative of $|x|$ is known to be $\text{sgn}(x)$ for $x\ne0$ and be undefined for $x=0$.

Hence for $x\ne0$

$$(x|x|)'=|x|+x\text{ sgn}(x)=2|x|.$$

For $x=0$, we can use the left and right derivatives, which are both $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is certainly differerentiable in all points $a \ne 0$ because
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 & x \ge 0 \\ -x^2 & x \le 0 \end{cases}$$
Certainly you know that a function $\phi$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only if both one-sided limits $\phi'_+(a) = \lim_{x \to a^+} \dfrac{\phi(x)- \phi(a)}{x-a}$ and $\phi'_-(a) = \lim_{x \to a^-} \dfrac{\phi(x)- \phi(a)}{x-a}$ exist and are equal.

In your case we get $f'_+(0) = f'_-(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Only $x=0$ the suspect point for differentiability.
$f(x)=x|x|=x^2, x\ge 0, x|x|=-x^2$ the left derivative is $Lf'(x)=-2x$ and right derivative is $Rf'(x)=-2x$. So at $x=0$, we have $Lf'(0)=0=Rf'(0)$, so $f(x)$ is differentiable even at $x=0$. Hence, $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere.